# Best way to invoke a function in a child component from the parent?

Tags: components, ractivejs

I have a ractive component that needs to performs a specific function, when a user asks it to. I.e., not when the component is being initialised, but some time afterwards.

The [ractive docs mention events are used to communicate between components and their parents](http://docs.ractivejs.org/edge/components) but only in the context of events bubbling from the child to the parent. In this case, we want the parent to invoke something on the child.

Alternatively, there's [ractive.findComponent()](http://docs.ractivejs.org/0.8/ractive-findcomponent) but the examples don't seem to use it much for ommunicating from the parent to the child.

I've made the following snippet which uses findComponent() and works (click **'Run Code Snippet'** then **'Full Page'**). However I'm not sure it's optimal:

```js
var coolWidget = Ractive.extend({
  data: {},
  template: `<span>Your favorite fruit is {{ fruit }}</span>`,
  data: function(){
    return {
      fruit: 'banana',
      doCoolThing: function(){
        var component = this;
        console.log('Going to change fruit...')
        setTimeout(function(){
          component.set('fruit', 'avocado')
        }, 3 * 1000)
      }
    }
  }
})

var ui = new Ractive({
  el: '.some-ui',
  data: { name: 'Mike'},
  components: {
    coolWidget
  },
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{ name}}</h1>
    <button>Press me</button>
    <coolWidget />
  `,
  oncomplete: function(){
    var widget = this.findComponent('coolWidget')
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
      widget.get('doCoolThing')();
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>
<div class="some-ui">

</div>
```

**What's the best way invoke a function in a child component from the parent?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `doCoolThing` is a top-level option...

```js
var coolWidget = Ractive.extend({
  data: {},
  template: `<span>Your favorite fruit is {{ fruit }}</span>`,
  data: function(){
    return {
      fruit: 'banana'
    }
  },
  doCoolThing: function(){
    var component = this;
    console.log('Going to change fruit...')
    setTimeout(function(){
      component.set('fruit', 'avocado')
    }, 3 * 1000)
  }
})
```

...then you can invoke the method like so:

```js
oncomplete: function(){
  var widget = this.findComponent('coolWidget')
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    widget.doCoolThing();
  })
}
```

This doesn't just *feel* better, it actually has a tangible benefit – `doCoolThing` sits on the `coolWidget` prototype, so only gets created once no matter how many widgets are instantiated. There's also no internal mucking around with context binding.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to expand on @rich-harris answer with a comment, but apparently this is too long.

If you want to have ractive manage your wiring a bit more, you could subscribe to and fire events from the root instance:

In widget onrender: `this.coolThingListener = this.root.on('doCoolThing *.doCoolThing', function() { /* cool thing here */ })`

In widget onunrender: `this.coolThingListener.cancel()`

In main instance template: `<button on-click="doCoolThing">Press me</button>`

When the button is pressed, the event will bubble to the root instance, which has a listener for any `doCoolThing` event (using the plain and starred version makes sure *any* nested component can trigger it in addition to events on the root instance). The only thing to watch out for is `this` in the component event handler (`coolThingListener`) will be the root instance, so you'll need to capture a component reference or use an arrow function.

There's an unsubscribe in `onunrender` in case you happen to have multiple instances of the component pop into existence over the life of the root.

Here's the whole thing together:

```js
var coolWidget = Ractive.extend({
  data: {},
  template: `<span>Your favorite fruit is {{ fruit }}</span>`,
  onrender: function(){
    var component = this;
    // if 'doCoolThing' might fire from another component, add '*.doCoolThing' to listener to matching child component events too
    this.coolThingListener = this.root.on( 'doCoolThing', function(){ 
      component.doCoolThing(); 
    });
  },
  onunrender: function(){
    this.coolThingListener.cancel();
  },
  data: function(){
    return {
      fruit: 'banana'
    }
  },
  doCoolThing: function(){
    console.log('Going to change fruit...')
    setTimeout(function(){
      this.set('fruit', 'avocado')
    }, 3 * 1000)
  }
})

var ui = new Ractive({
  el: '.some-ui',
  data: { name: 'Mike'},
  components: {
    coolWidget
  },
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{ name}}</h1>
    <button on-click="doCoolThing">Press me</button>
    <coolWidget />
  `
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Is `'doCoolThing *.doCoolThing'` correct? Wouldn't it be something like `coolWidget doCoolThing`?

Comment: @mikemaccana in this specific case, you could drop the `*.doCoolThing` since the event is originating from the root and won't be namespaced. If it could come from a child component, the star listener would catch it because events grow a namespace the first time they cross a component boundary (bubble to their immediate parent). Having multiple names separated by spaces is just shorthand for subscribing to multiple events.

Comment: Could you update your example to match your comment? That would make it a little clearer. Also can you do event binding with addEventListener(), rather than in HTML?

Comment: @mikemaccana I've updated the example to only subscribe to local `doCoolThing` events. The event `on-click="doCoolThing"` actually _does_ use `addEventListener` behind the scenes. `on-click` is a Ractive directive that is a convenient shortcut for "go ahead and add an event listener for 'click' events to this element when you render it to the actual DOM." It aims for the convenience of `<button onclick="...">` without all of the associated horribleness.